# Where to write Label in Listview In Android

Tags: java, eclipse, listview, android-studio, android-listview

I am new to Android. I'm confused by `ListView` label. Let's say, I have two dates in my `ListView`. The two different date labels are different.
So where I can put the label text in my `ListView`?

Image for clarification:
[image]

Code for `ListView`, **Case Date** is not displayed.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caddress"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:textColor="@color/md_grey_400"
    android:text="Case Date :"
    android:textSize="11sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cddate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caddress"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/md_grey_400"
    android:text=" 01-01-2011"
    android:textSize="11sp" />
```

Comment: What do you mean with "label"? Also, Case Date is shown in your screen shot..?

Comment: Case date is Label for 01/02/15,  sorry for I am new to Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you mean by listview label? 
Every listview should inflate a layout for each list item. This layout will be automaticaly inflated for each element of collection you passed in your adapter constructor and is an appropriate place to put yout date textviews. Did you familiar with ListView Adapter?

SOLUTION: Try this in adapter, where you assigning value to view dateView.setText("Case Date:" + date.toString())

Comment: yes , but my question is i have Array of Date. but i wont to display it like date = 01/02/15;  date = 02/02/2015 , date = 03/02/15  the before list item the label date is there ,how i can put that label in  my Listview.

Comment: So you talking about displaying format? Try this in adapter, where you assigning value to view dateView.setText("Case Date:" + date.toString())